# How to assign different controller method to handle two fifferent forms on the same page

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a a jsp page which contains two forms created using spring.tld.
I would like to assign different Controller method to process each form submit and since both requests are going to be POST I can't do it with just

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

So I'm looking for another parameter to distinguish between the two requests and looks like it should either be the header or the value.

Could someone please provide a simple implementation example of these two approachs from the view and the controller side?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the RequestMapping you can specify the URL path your method will respond to.  For instance,

```
@RequestMapping( value="/myFirstForm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String myFirstFormHandler() {}

@RequestMapping( value="/mySecondForm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String mySecondFormHandler() {}
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping

Comment: Thanks. I actually got that one already, I'm interested in the header option if possible as it seems a bit "cleaner" approach

Comment: having a form submit to a specific URL is pretty standard HTML procedure so I have a hard time seeing how setting some header would be "cleaner"